# How can i create hierarchical url in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net, database, url-routing, hierarchical-data, taxonomy

I want to use hierarchical url for my application.How can i create?

For example my database hierarchy as follow,

```
  My product table
     |
     |--> Electronics
             |
             |--> Television
                       |
                       |--> Led Tv
                               |
                               |--> Samsung Led Tv
                               |--> Philips Led Tv
                               |--> LG Led Tv
```

i want to create hierarchical url such as http://mydomain.com/product/electronics/television/led_tv/samsung_led_tv

Comment: Learn about URL rewriting and routing.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [URL-rewriting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine).

In ASP.NET you can leverage IIS URL Rewriting module in order to get it:

http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite

Answer (score 1):

Use URL Rewrite

http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2012/11/07/url-rewrite-protocol-http-https-in-the-action.aspx

or

[ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc) for SEO (Search Engine Optimization) friendly URL.

Answer (score 0):

i have found a sample about my issue. http://erraticdev.blogspot.com/2011/01/custom-aspnet-mvc-route-class-with.html